# When was the last confirmed time that Master Chief ate something in the Halo universe?

Tags: halo

It occurred to me that I haven't seen Master Chief eat anything in-game.  He doesn't participate in a peaceful non-combat situation after the beginning of Halo 2. If we assumed that he ate breakfast that morning, then was that the last time he ate?

Basically, I'm wondering what the extended universe mentions about Master Chief eating and when the last time was that he ate anything in the current timeline.

Comment: He eats a bunch of times in the novels. Does that count?

Comment: I would think that would count as extended universe material, get some excerpts or at least titles and you have an answer.